# Remove a System Form Item in SAP B1

Tags: sapb1

Is there a way to remove an item of a system form, like a matrix, programmatically in SAP Business One? Or can I make a matrix invisible?

Answer (score 0):

Menu "Tools" -> "Edit Form UI" -> Right click on the item -> Hide.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove item with code, open form in visual studio and just delete what you want.